# Why there is no possibility of scrollview scrolled when added contents dynamically.?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using scroll view. In my scenario, When contents are added dynamically in content view of scroll view. The view height must be increased automatically and content is added to the bottom with scrolling functionality. I tried the following. There is no particular way of scroll functionality. I don't know why scrolling is much complicated in iOS. Why scroll view not work the way like table view scrolling, table view taking any number of amount and scrolls. Finding youtube videos too not working as it has fixed height in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your scrollview you must add a UIView. Add a height constraint to the UIView and programatically change the height of the UIView depending on the content you are adding to this UIView. This scrollview will work if the height is large.